# I am trying to display variable names and num2str representations of their values in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, disp

I am trying to produce the following:The new values of x and y are -4 and 7, respectively, using the disp and num2str commands. I tried to do this disp('The new values of x and y are num2str(x) and num2str(y) respectively'), but it gave num2str instead of the appropriate values. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Colin mentioned, one option would be converting the numbers to strings using [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/disp.html), concatenating all strings manually and feeding the final result into [`disp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html). Unfortunately, it can get *very* awkward and tedious, especially when you have a lot of numbers to print.

Instead, you can harness the power of [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html), which is very similar in MATLAB to its C programming language counterpart. This produces shorter, more elegant statements, for instance:

```
disp(sprintf('The new values of x and y are %d and %d respectively', x, y))
```

You can control how variables are displayed using the format specifiers. For instance, if `x` is not necessarily an integer, you can use `%.4f`, for example, instead of `%d`.

EDIT: like Jonas pointed out, you can also use [`fprintf(...)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) instead of `disp(sprintf(...))`.

Comment: +1 Very neat. I'll probably start doing things this way from now on :-)

Comment: @ColinTBowers: Instead of `disp(sprintf(...))`, you can also use `fprintf(...)`. Less typing :)

Comment: @Jonas +1, I'm putting that into my answer as well.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
disp(['The new values of x and y are ', num2str(x), ' and ', num2str(y), ', respectively']);
```

You can actually omit the commas too, but IMHO they make the code more readable.

By the way, what I've done here is concatenated 5 strings together to form one string, and then fed that single string into the `disp` function. Notice that I essentially concatenated the string using the same syntax as you might use with numerical matrices, ie `[x, y, z]`. The reason I can do this is that matlab stores character strings internally AS numeric row vectors, with each character denoting an element. Thus the above operation is essentially concatenating 5 numeric row vectors horizontally!

One further point: Your code failed because matlab treated your num2str(x) as a string and not as a function. After all, you might legitimately want to print "num2str(x)", rather than evaluate this using a function call. In my code, the first, third and fifth strings are defined as strings, while the second and fourth are functions which evaluate to strings.